# When booted up kernel_task gradually uses whole ram and swap

Tags: macos, high-sierra

[image]

macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

MacBook Air Mid 2011

Comment: Look at Activity Monitor, set to All Processes. What does it show for memory pressure? Screenshot of the whole window sorted by Memory, high to the top, would be good too.

Comment: Can you run `kextstat | grep -v com.apple` and report back?